# ¿Cómo convertir los valores menores a 0 de una matriz?

Tags: r

Tras crear en código de programación R una matriz de propiedades `matrix(-4:4, nrow=3, ncol=3)`, ¿cómo puedo convertir los valores negativos contenidos a 0? Mi gratitud por adelantado.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias formas, tal vez la más sencilla es usar la función vectorizada `ifelse()`:

```
m <- matrix(-4:4, nrow=3, ncol=3)
ifelse(m < 0, 0, m)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    2
[2,]    0    0    3
[3,]    0    1    4
```

O bien con un subsetting, a los valores menores a 0 de la matriz, le asignamos el 0.

```
m[m < 0] <- 0
m
```